# How to check contact between two game objects with one having child game objects that change position

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want to check contact between one game object (ObjA which has a box collider and a rigid body) and another game object (ObjB) which has two child game objects. The child objects of ObjB change positions slightly. I haven't set a box collider for ObjB because I don't need it to react to physics, I just need to tell when one object (ObjA) is in contact/touches it. How can this be done?

Comment: The title of your questions are long. You need to shorten them and put the long version in the body of the question. Anyways, Edit your question and add what you have tried to it. Also add the proper language tag.

Comment: In order to detect collision/contact between 2 objects it is absolutely needed that both contain a `Collider` component.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a box collider to ObjB and check the boolean "Is Trigger". This will still allow things to go through it and not collide or bounce off.
However, now instead of onCollision enter, you need to use onTriggerEnter as done here:
http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/581977/how-to-get-collision-point-when-using-ontriggerent.html